# Adaboost Notation Confusion

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

The adaboost algorithm is as follows:

> $\mathbf{Input}$: sequence of m examples $<(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m)>$
>   with the labels $y_i \in Y = \{1,...,k\}$
>   weak learning algorithm WeakLearn
>   integer T specifying the number of iterations
>   $\mathbf{Initialize}$: $D_i(i) = \frac{1}{m}$ for all i
>   $\mathbf{Do}$ t = 1,2,...,T:
>   1. Call WeakLearn, providing it with distribution $D_t$
>   2. Get back a hypothesis $h_t : X \rightarrow Y$
>   3. Calculate the error of $\displaystyle h_t: \epsilon_t = \sum_{i:h_t(x_i)\neq y_i} D_i(i)$
>   If $\epsilon_t > 0.5$, then set $T = t - 1$ and abort loop.
>   4. $\displaystyle \beta_t = \frac{\epsilon_t}{1-\epsilon_t}$
>   5. Update distribution $D_t$ as $\displaystyle D_{t+1} = \frac{D_t(i)}{Z_t} \times \begin{cases}
> \beta_t,  & \text{if $h_t(x_i) = y_i$} \\
> 1, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases} $
>   where $Z_t$ is a normalization constant (chosen so that $D_{t+1}$ will be a distribution)

My confusion is regarding two steps:

1. What does the notation for the error, $\epsilon_t$ mean? Does it mean add all the weights if there is a missclassification?
2. What does the statement `If $\epsilon_t > 0.5$, then set T = t - 1 and abort loop.` mean? Is it stating to abort the leap (as in `break`) or do not count this as an iteration and `continue` to loop?

Some details: I am actually randomly choosing from $D_i$ based on the sample weights. The idea to generate a weak SVM classifier.

Comment: This is a fun question! (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As Lucas already said (+1), yes, your intuition is correct; that is the sum of the weighted error terms.
2. This steps is *indeed* awkward for `Adaboost`, because it is *not* the `Adaboost` commonly used but actually the early version of what we call `Adaboost` algorithm, namely `Adaboost.M1`; it is presented in Freund & Schapire (1996) *[Experiments with a New Boosting Algorithm](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/teaching/COLT/boostingexperiments.pdf)*. `Adaboost.M1` explicitly encoded what the authors describe as: "*(...) Adaboost (...), theoretically can be used to significantly reduce the error of any learning algorithm that consistently generates classifiers whose performance is a little better than random guessing*". Therefore as soon as $\epsilon_t > 0.5$, the iteration stopped.

Some further commentary on Point 2: As more people studied the algorithm it became clear that the break condition was unnecessary. The reproduction of `Adaboost.M1`, simply as `Adaboost`, in Friedman et al. (2000) *[Additive logistic regression: a statistical view of boosting](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1016218223)*  does not include this "hot-fix"/break condition. If anything it was superfluous for Friedman et al.'s core notion that the: "*AdaBoost algorithm (population version) builds an additive logistic regression model via Newton-like updates for minimizing $E(e^{-yF(x)})$*". To that extent, the break condition in `Adaboost.M1` became uninterpretable when we moved to `LogitBoost`, `BrownBoost` and other boosting variances. F&S obviously knew this; it is evident even in their 1996 paper; the algorithm `Adaboost.M2` does not include any break conditions. As a final note, I think that the CV.SE  thread *[Binary classifiers with accuracy < 50% in Adaboost?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397446/binary-classifiers-with-accuracy-50-in-adaboost)* will also help one's understanding of the issue. It discusses why this break condition is indeed redundant; in short, we can naturally "flip" the signs of a "bad" classification result to get a "good" one.

Comment: Thank you, that made a lot of sense. Is it possible for the error to increase in the AdaBoost M1 implementation?

Comment: +1 That's really interesting!

Comment: @saad: *In probability* the training error should not increase; if anything there is an additional early stopping condition to guarantee that.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you. Can you also explain how the normalization term, Zt, is computed? Zt, as I understand, is the a term that makes Dt into a distribution (i.e. a sum of 1). In that case, is Zt a sum of Zt or Zt+1?

Comment: Yes, $Z_t$ is used to make $D_t$ sum up to 1. $Z_t$ would be $\sum_i D_{t+1}(i)$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. The notation $i:h(x_i) \neq y_i$ means you'll pick $i$'s that satisfy the given condition; in this case that the computed hypothesis does not correspond to the true value.
2. This step looks weird when compared to other descriptions of this algorithm ([this one](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=es&lr=&id=_-rjBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Combining+Artificial+Neural+Nets:+Ensemble+and+Modular+Multi-Net+Systems&ots=wszsKFm2gI&sig=6PZkD_Pv-_oKJwDw8XshTH9_m1c#v=onepage&q=Combining%20Artificial%20Neural%20Nets%3A%20Ensemble%20and%20Modular%20Multi-Net%20Systems&f=false) (p. 58), for example). Specially when you consider that there are still steps to come after abortion, and that convergence would not be achieved this way.

I think there's something off. If you can provied the source, we can maybe check it further.

Comment: I can't figure out 2) either.

Comment: @MatthewDrury It is the Adaboost.M1 formulation, mid to late 90's. It is a break; it tries to encapsulate the idea that the learner is better than chance. I might expand on this tonight!

Comment: Yah, I can see that it's saying "This weak lerner learned worse than a coin flip, so bail", but it's unclear to me how that is even possible.  Would enjoy the expansion!

Comment: @MatthewDrury: You are right, it is not possible. "Most of us" learned boosting in the context of Friedman et al. (2000) and Friedman (2001). Adaboost.M1 predates these by almost half a decade so our priors aren't exactly flat!